# Using express to serve an Angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I planning to serve my Angular index.html with express.

Is it possible to make a call to service which can populate a node model.  Then pass this model value to index.html.

For example, I call a service from a trusted source within our compnay that gives me back a few  files which I will write to the index file.

I could do this in JavaScript with index.html at runtime, but I think it woud be better if the node server did this as it bootstrapped and served the index.html.

I cannot seem to find how this is done or a common approach.

I have done this before in a .NET/Angular app but this Node/Express is a new approach for me.

thanks

Comment: Could you just call the service from your angular4 component when the application is being requested in the browser?

Comment: I tried that but I am getting some errors and I think it might be because of the nature of injecting into the <head> elements at run time instead of bootstrapping with by the server.   I think it could probably end up working but doesn't seem clean.  Was hoping for something similar to what I did in .NET using the MVC model which is populated by the server side as the app loads

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319229/angular-2-bootstrap-application-from-external-data thread and see if that helps.